# How to calculate the actual distance flown by a golf ball?

Tags: calculus, physics

I am interested in finding out what the actual distance is flown by a golf ball on a drive.  You can assume no wind, 10 degree launch angle, goes straight down the middle of the fairway (no draw, no slice...) and no erratic backspin on the ball (so it wont "balloon" but will have stable flight).  You can also assume that the ball flies 200 yards of linear distance (relative to the ground).  So basically I would like to know how much "extra" distance does the ball fly relative to the 200 yards of linear distance?  I was thinking somewhere on the order of 15% more (30 yards more) but that is just a guess.

The answer need not be exact.

Also I am not sure what tag I should use so if someone has a better one go ahead and change it or just tell me and I will change it.

Comment: Are you including air resistance? Do you want to include bouncing or just where it first hits?

Comment: Well of course there will be air resistance but I already stated the ball goes 200 yards linear distance (typical for an amateur golfer).  You can ignore anything that happens after the ball bounces.  I am interested in just the flight.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://www.golf-simulators.com/physics.htm) that discusses the trajectory of a golf ball in great detail. It doesn't answer your question though.

Comment: The shape of the flight (and hence length) is different if you have air resistance or not.

Comment: I have read multiple links already but I haven't found my answer to this specific question.

Comment: # Ian Miller.  But I gave the information about the linear length of the ball flight so from that, just use a "normal" flight path and somehow calculate the actual distance traveled in the air.  I mentioned no erratic spins on the ball so if you want to borrow from other's research, just assume medium (normal) backspin and no sidespin and no wind.

Comment: 'Normal' would include air resistance which makes the problem significantly more involved mathematically. It is a small change compared to no air resistance so I guess I'm asking how accurate a value are you after?

Comment: Just an approximation like "ballpark 15% more" than linear distance.

Comment: Wow was my estimate WAY off.

Comment: @Ian: If you look at the pictures in [my link](http://www.golf-simulators.com/physics.htm), you will see that air resistance has a major effect on the shape of the trajectory. It is not at all a small change.

Comment: @TonyK I only used the word small in the context of the OP wanting a rough answer. All the answers below have assume no air resistance so should be within a 'ballpark' of the right answer.

Comment: [This link](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e95uI7kgVJw/UX1CZ0pPkkI/AAAAAAAAAYI/eXoFF-mP7_E/s1600/golfball-lift.png) addresses the question of the optimum launch angle, settling on $16^\circ$ in real-life golf. The $17^\circ$ trajectory in the final diagram is clearly much more than $0.5\%$ longer than the horizontal distance $-$ I would estimate it by eye as $10-15\%$ longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumptions that you make, the golf ball is basically free falling without losing horizontal speed and is therefore described by a parabola:
\begin{equation}
y=-ax^2+bx+c,
\end{equation}
where $x$ is the horizontal distance and $y$ is the height of the ball. We know that when $x=\pm 100$, the ball is at the ground, so 
\begin{equation}
0=-a*10000+b*100+c
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
0=-a*10000-b*100+c
\end{equation}
If we take the sum and the difference of these formulas, we get
\begin{equation}
0=-a*20000+2*c \qquad \text{and}\qquad 0=b*200.
\end{equation}
This gives us two relations, resulting in $b=0$ and $c=10000*a$. The question is now to determine $c$ or $a$ and we have one given fact left: the 10 degree launch angle. How would we translate this launch angle into mathematics? A 10 degree angle corresponds to a slope of 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(10)\approx 0.176.
\end{equation}
This must be the slope at $x=-100$. So we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=-100}=-2ax+b|_{x=-100}=200a=0.176
\end{equation}
So, we find $a=0.176/200=0.00088$ and we now have the total trajectory of the ball
\begin{equation}
y=-0.00088 x^2 +8.8.
\end{equation}
We can use this formula to find the length of the path that the ball follows. We also see immediately that 8.8 is the maximal height that the ball reaches. The length of the trajectory can be calculated by
\begin{equation}
\int_{-100}^{100} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx=\int_{-100}^{100} \sqrt{1+(-2*0.00088*x)^2} dx \approx 201.028
\end{equation}
This last integral is easily done with [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-100%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%5Csqrt%7B1%2B(-2*0.00088*x)%5E2%7D+dx)! or some graphical calculator. Or you could it algebraically as
\begin{equation}
\int_{-100}^{100} \sqrt{1+(-2*0.00088*x)^2} dx = \left(-2*0.00088 x \sqrt{1+(-2*0.00088)^2 x^2}+\frac{\sinh^{(-1)}{(-2*0.00088 x)}}{-4*0.00088}\right)\Big|_{-100}^{100}.
\end{equation}

In short, 201.028 is the total length of the ball's trajectory. So, it does only 1.028 extra yards. This is not so much as you expected, so maybe the 10 degree angle is a bit on the small side.

You can probably retrace the steps above to find the trajectory length for another launch angle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the curve that a ball moves is given by a parabola. This would actually be the case, if we conducted such an experiment in a vacuum - in the real world, air resistance etc. would make the problem much more complicated (but this approximation will suffice for us).

Now we launch the ball in our coordinate system at $x = 0$ and at an angle of $\alpha$. and the ball lands after a horizontal distance of $d$. Our model function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ must satisfy three conditions:

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $f'(0) = \tan \alpha$
3. $f(d) = 0$

From the first condition we can conclude $c = 0$. From the second condition, we get $f'(0) = b = \tan \alpha$ and our third condition yields
$0 = f(d) = ad^2 + bd$, i.e. $a = -\frac{b}{d}$. This means our model function is $f(x) = -\frac{b}{d}x^2 + bx$ with $b = \tan \alpha$.

Now we want to calculate the arc length of $f$ over the interval $[0, d]$, the formula for this is given by
$$L = \int_0^d \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}\, dx = \int_0^d \sqrt{1 + \left(b - 2\frac{b}{d}x\right)^2} \, dx = d \cdot \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + b^2(1 - 2x)^2} \, dt = d \frac{b \sqrt{1 + b^2} + \sinh^{-1}(b)}{2b}$$

The last integral was calculated via [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt(1%20%2B%20b%5E2*(1-2x)%5E2)%20from%200%20to%201) (because I am lazy).

Now if we actually plug in $\alpha = 10^\circ$ we get $b = \tan 10^\circ \approx 0.176$ and the golf ball travelled a length of approximately $1.005d$, which is $0.5\%$ more than the horizontal distance

Comment: 0.5% seems very low to me.  How can that be if the ball will rise so much?  I suppose if we knew the apex (the highest the ball will get during the drive), we could approximate it using a triangle shape.  When I did that using 10 degrees as the angle, I get 1.5% increase in distance (to 203 yards).

Comment: The apex has a height of $f(d/2) = bd/4$. Using the Pythagorean theorem to approximate the length with $2$ triangles we get a length of $2 \sqrt{(d/2)^2 + (bd/4)^2} = d \sqrt{1 + (b/2)^2}$, which is only a $0.4\%$ increase compared to the horizontal distance.

Comment: Wow I must be really bad at math cuz I just drew a triangular path with the ball flying directly towards the apex at 10 degrees then dropping back to the landing spot (at 200 linear yards) and I got 203 yards total for that path and since the straight line (segment) is the shortest path from the tee to the apex and from the apex to the landing spot, how can a curved path be less distance than that?  I think it should be more.  If the ball help the 10 degrees up angle up until the apex, it would reach 53 feet.  Of course it wont but I grossly simplified this method to get an approximation.

Comment: It is deceptive that the ball can go so high on a drive and have so much hang time but the actual distance it travels is not much more than the linear distance.  I am actually quite surprised at the results.  I was thinking on a 200 yard drive it would go 230 yards in the air in the curved path.  That obviously (now) is WAY off.

Comment: At a $10^\circ$ angle and $200$ yards horizontal distance, the apex has an actual height of only $8.8$ yards, not the $17.6$ yards you used as an approximation. Note that the angle of $10^\circ$ is only the angle at the beginning of the shot, not the angle between the apex and the horizontal line.

Comment: Your answers were quite good but I gave the checkmark to the other person who answered cuz they had a much lower reputation score. @Dominik

Answer (score 1):

To expand the above calculations to describe a real golf ball trajectory, we need to include the effects of *drag* and *lift* (the *Magnus* force), when the equations become:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}= - k_D|\mathbf{v}|\mathbf{v} +
        k_L\, |\mathbf{v}|(\boldsymbol{\hat \omega}\times \mathbf{v})+ \mathbf{g}, \quad (\text{m/s}^2)$

where $\mathbf{v}(x,y,z)$ is the velocity vector, $\hat \omega$ the unit angular velocity vector, $\mathbf{g}$ gravitational acceleration vector, $t \ge t_0$ time, and $k_D$ and $k_L$ are coefficients for drag and lift forces respectively. These coefficients in turn are dependent upon the balls's spin-rate $S(t)$ and are usually defined empirically by suitable correlations.
It is the lift resulting from golf ball back-spin and surface dimples that largely contributes to the extra distance travelled, over and above that which would be achieved without this effect.

Finally, ambient conditions have to be taken into account, e.g. wind speed, air density, etc.

A fully expanded mathematical and physical description can be found in:

Griffiths (2016), *Numerical Methods Using R*, Cambridge University Press., Chap 9.

The full computer code (in open source language R) to perform various simulations can be downloaded from [www.pdecomp.net](http://www.pdecomp.net)

Answer (score 0):

This is a non mathematical answer but still mildly interesting and worth mentioning.  For someone that really wanted to know this but didn't have the math skills to solve it (like me), I suppose someone could record the flight of the ball on their smartphone such that the entire ballflight could be recorded.  Then they would take a piece of string and trace the ballflight on the smartphone screen.  Then they would simply measure the length of the string relative to the length of the flat path (along the ground).  Solutions like this is why I didn't major in math in college.  I would always want to do things in a simpler (non mathematical) way.